# Wild card operator returning blank result - encoding error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the below query I'm running in SSMS '17:

```
select gc.TEXT
from GENERATED_CAMPS gc
where gc.Identifier = '60272747'
    and gc.TEXT like  '%your%'
```

The result is a single blank cell.  In the where clause i specify that it must contain the word `your`.  Does this maybe indicate that I have an encoding issue in my SSMS?

What have I tried?

1. Researching the wild card operator
2. Copy pasting the results to notepad with utf8 etc

Edit:
this is the column definition of the field in question:

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
TEXTSMS nvarchar    no           510                    yes     (n/a)   (n/a)                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Update Saving to .rpt gives:

" S a v o r   y o u r 1 1 9 5 2 7 # 7 6 "(cut short)

and various other measures:

```
select gc.TEXT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    , PATINDEX('%your%', gc.TEXT) 'patindex'
    , LEN(gc.text) 'length'
    , CONVERT(varchar(MAX), gc.TEXT) 'convert'
    , cast(gc.TEXT as nvarchar) 'cast'
    , CAST( CAST(gc.TEXT AS VARBINARY) AS varchar) 'Cast cast'

from GENERATED_CAMPS gc
where gc.Identifier = '60272747'
    and gc.TEXT like  '%your%'
```

gives:

```
(No column name)    patindex    length  convert cast    Cast cast
                    14          67
```

Also tried changing my `Results to Grid` to ‘Arial Unicode MS‘ as [here](https://clinthuijbers.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/how-to-display-unicode-characters-in-grid-results-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/)

Comment: You have enough rep around here to know we need some details. Where is the table definition? Sample data?

Comment: @SeanLange I've added the column definition.  However, I am asking about one single cell that I can't copy and paste.  Options for posting this sample data would be appreciated

Comment: Try `SELECT PATINDEX('%your%', gc.TEXT)` to find out *where* SQL Server thinks the match is, then `SUBSTRING` to narrow it down further if necessary. Yes, SSMS can truncate long fields, but I don't think 510 is already problematic. Still, you can also try "results to text" instead of "results to grid" and see if it spits out some more, if for example newlines are an issue. Other useful techniques for the general case: `LEN`, `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)`, `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))`. I've not yet seen a field I couldn't crack.

Comment: Instead of `CAST( CAST(gc.TEXT AS VARBINARY) AS varchar)`, do `CAST(gc.TEXT AS VARBINARY(MAX))` and study the results. This gives you the actual Unicode codepoints of the entire string, and will allow you to see (well, with some studying) what characters are actually in the field. You may find it contains control characters that cause SSMS to truncate the display. In any case, your results at least establish that yes, there is a "your" in the string, and possibly other weirdness.